# CakePHP - Anchor class not changing (undefined variable $action)

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller, cakephp

I want to add a class to my anchor link when it is active but its not working. How would I have to declare the $action variable then?

Version:

```
 4.2.9
```

Error:

```
Undefined variable: action [ROOT\templates\layout\default.php, line 108]
```

templates/layout/default.php

```
<li>
    <?= $this->Html->link(
        '<div class="icon"></div>'.__('Summary'),
        ['controller' => 'modules', 'action' => 'summary'],
        [
        'escapeTitle' => false,
        'class' => 'icon-summary '.( ($controller == 'Modules' && $action == 'summary') ? 'active' : '')
        ]
    ) ?>
</li>
```

In my ModulesController.php

```
  public function summary()
  {
      $modules = $this->getAllModules();
  }
```

Routing parameter from DebugKit

```
'controller' => 'Modules',
'action' => 'summary',
'pass' => [ ],
'plugin' => null,
'_matchedRoute' => '/{controller}/{action}/*',
'_ext' => null,
]
```

Comment: It's because there is no variable called `$action` defined here. There's a component of the route called `action`, but you haven't done anything to extract it from there.

Comment: Where would I have to extract it? In my ModulesController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my `AppController.php` I have inserted code below in my `beforeRender()` function. Now I have access to the `action` variable.

```
$this->set('action', $this->request->getParam('action'));
```

many thanks